# customizing gb4e subexamples (not about cross-reference)

Tags: numbering, linguistics, gb4e

I'm using the gb4e for labeling examples in a semantic paper. The examples come with a specific context, and I want to mention that under this specific context, there are at least 2 felicitous answers. What I want is sth like:

(36) Context: It's raining outside.

A: It's a really nice weather today. --> instead of a.

B: Yes, you are right. --> instead of b.

B': Yes, but it is so hot. --> instead of c.

B'': No, you are wrong.  --> instead of d.

(no spaces among these subexamples)

I understand by using other packages, e.g. *linguex* I can resolve the problem, but I was wondering if I can change any setting in the gb4e package to continue using it.

Thanks so much!

Here is the MWE (Sorry if the format looks terrible):

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
     \usepackage{gb4e}
    \begin{exe}
    \ex Context: It's raining outside. 
    \begin{xlist}
    \ex[A:] It's a really nice weather today. 
    \ex[B:] Yes, you are right.
    \ex[B':] Yes, but it is so hot.
    \ex[B'':] No, you are wrong.
    \end{xlist}
    \end{exe}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.stack... Can you provide a MWE of what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing this a lot, I would create a modified version of the `gb4e` `\exi` command to line up everything properly. I've called this `\exk`, and its corresponding `\sn` version, `\snk`.  This is preferable to redefining `\exi` itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\exk[1]{\item[{\makebox[1.5em][l]{#1}}]\@ifnextchar [{\@exj}{}}
\newcommand\snk{\exk{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex Context: It’s raining outside.
\begin{xlist}
\exk{A:}{It's a really nice weather today.}
\exk{B:}{Yes, you are right.}
\exk{B’:}{Yes, but it is so hot.}
\exk{B’’:}{No, you are wrong.}
\snk{Some example}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 0):

For providing custom example identifiers you can use `\exi{<identifier>}`, as explained in Section 1.2 (page 4) of the [gb4e manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gb4e/gb4e-doc.pdf). Identifiers are not left aligned by default, so you could consider using B<sub>0</sub>, B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub> to make them all the same width (although in linguistics most people probably use the prime notation).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex Context: It's raining outside. 
\begin{xlist}
\exi{A:} It's a really nice weather today. 
\exi{B:} Yes, you are right.
\exi{B':} Yes, but it is so hot.
\exi{B'':} No, you are wrong.
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]